# Space between images in GridView Android

Tags: android, gridview

I am using GridView to show the images(Only tablet) but getting too much space between the images searched about this but still didnt get the solution, find below xml file,java code and screenshot where am going wrong. 
My XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.naveenbannikoppa.grid.AndroidGridViewDisplayImages" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview_android_example"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_weight="100"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dip"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dip"
    android:clipChildren="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:numColumns="3" >
</GridView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Java File

```
public class AndroidGridViewDisplayImages extends AppCompatActivity {

    GridView androidGridView;

    Integer[] imageIDs = {
            R.drawable.mobile_app_41, R.drawable.mobile_app_41, R.drawable.mobile_app_42,
            R.drawable.mobile_app_43, R.drawable.mobile_app_46, R.drawable.mobile_app_46,
            R.drawable.mobile_app_46, R.drawable.mobile_app_41, R.drawable.mobile_app_42,

    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gridview_android_example_with_image);

        androidGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview_android_example);
        androidGridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapterGridView(this));

        androidGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                    View v, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Grid Item " + (position + 1) + " Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }

    public class ImageAdapterGridView extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;

        public ImageAdapterGridView(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return imageIDs.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView mImageView;

            if (convertView == null) {
                mImageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                mImageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150, 150));
                mImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                mImageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

                mImageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            } else {
                mImageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }
            mImageView.setImageResource(imageIDs[position]);
            return mImageView;
        }
    }
}
```

Screen Shot

[image]

I want Like this

[image]

Comment: you always want 3 columns in 1 row right? it's ok if more than 3 columns in 1 row

Comment: yes always want 3 columns, @PhanVanLinh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always want to have 3 columns in one row, you should calculate height of each item depends on the screen height (it will be equals `screenheight-gap/numberofitem`)

```
if (convertView == null) {
    int screenHeight = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
    int screenWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels; 

    int height = MIN(screenHeight,screenWidth);
    int numberOfCollumns = 3;
    int verticalSpace = 10;
    int itemHeight = (height - (numberOfCollumns + 1) * horizontalSpace) / numberOfCollumns;

    mImageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    //mImageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150, 150));
    mImageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(itemHeight, itemHeight));

    ...
}
```

and in you xml, change `GridView` `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview_android_example"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    ...
/>
```

Comment: Images become big, i am unable to show 3*3 matrix view want to show all the 9 images without scrolling @PhanVanLinh

Comment: @Naveen you can increase the `horizontalSpace` value as you want

Comment: Still not working, if I increase horizontalSpace to show again am getting same which I posted screenshot above @PhanVanLinh

Comment: @Naveen can you use the photoshop or paint to draw the screen that you want to achieve, then I will easy to understand what you want

Comment: Yes best idea wait for 5 min @PhanVanLinh

Comment: I added screenshot in the question, can u please give and better view like that @PhanVanLinh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112661/discussion-between-naveen-and-phan-vn-linh).

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/gridview"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:columnWidth="100dp"
   android:numColumns="auto_fit"
   android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
   android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
   android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
   android:gravity="center"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code, increase vertical spacing...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gridview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:columnWidth="100dp"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:gravity="center"
/>
```

Comment: Not Working, android:numColumns should be 3 instead autofit. @SikanderBhutto

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no problem in your layout. The problem is size of images you are used. try after changing size of images.

Comment: What should be the size of the image? @NikhilSuwalka

Comment: developer console for size of  images for different layouts. and also check this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_grid_view.htm)